# Does any City have POIA (Public Online Information act) laws in place?

Tags: usa, city, legal, sunlight-foundation

A few years ago, [Sunlight Foundation advocated for the Public Online Information Act (POIA)](http://sunlightfoundation.com/policy/poia/). Do you know of any city that has adopted such a law or statue?

> In the age of the Internet, government is transparent only when public
>   information is available online. The Public Online Information Act
>   (POIA) is legislation, introduced by Rep. Steve Israel in the House
>   and Sen. Jon Tester in the Senate, that embraces a new formula for
>   transparency: public equals online. No longer will antiquated
>   government disclosure practices bury public information in
>   out-of-the-way offices and in outmoded formats.
>
> POIA requires executive branch agencies to publish all publicly
>   available information on the Internet in a timely fashion and in
>   user-friendly formats. It also creates an advisory committee to help
>   develop government-wide Internet publication policies.

Comment: I am afraid that, as currently stated, this question is a “big list” type question: it asks for many short answers, all equally valid (and it has already received 4 such answers). I voted to **close as not constructive**. It might be edited into a more fitting question, such as *“where can I find a directory of cities with POIA laws in place?”* or *“what was the first city to have a POIA law in place?”* or …

Answer (score 6):

The closest law I've seen to being as comprehensive as POIA is NYC's Local Law 11, but many other cities have an open data law with looser language about whether "all" public data has to be put online.

More broadly speaking there's a fairly comprehensive list of city open data laws at:
http://wiki.civiccommons.org/Open_Data_Policy It's also worth noting that most cities are covered by the FOIA laws in place by the state that they're in. You can find a list of those laws at http://www.rcfp.org/open-government-guide

Answer (score 6):

POIA was proposed in California. See this blogpost by my former colleague Melanie Buck. http://sunlightfoundation.com/blog/2012/01/13/public-online-information-act-inspires-transparency-advocacy-in-california/

It also was proposed in eastern europe, although I cannot remember where anymore.

By the way, for more background information POIA, check out http://sunlightfoundation.com/policy/poia/

Answer (score 5):

NYC has its Open Data Law here - 
http://nycopendata.pediacities.com/wiki/index.php/NYC_Open_Data

Answer (score 4):

Chicago has an executive order that has some of these elements:

http://chicago.legistar.com/LegislationDetail.aspx?ID=1254930&GUID=B8473045-0917-495B-A1D2-E739A03CB962

Answer (score 3):

Philadelphia has its Open Data executive order available on GitHub: https://gist.github.com/PhillyCDO/3623582

Details on the implementation of the plan are published in this GitHub repo:  https://github.com/CityOfPhiladelphia/open-gov-phl

You might also be interested in the open data guidebook for agencies the Chief Data Officer released for public review: http://phillymdoblog.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/an-open-data-guidebook-for-city-departments/