# How does the Sunlight Foundation relate to Open Data?

Tags: nonprofit, sunlight-foundation

Here are a couple of questions where the Sunlight Foundation is referenced:

- [Does any City have POIA (Public Online Information act) laws in place?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9/does-any-city-have-poia-public-online-information-act-laws-in-place)
- [Open Data Scorecards?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/78/open-data-scorecards)

What is the purpose of the Sunlight Foundation, how does it accomplish its goals, who is the Sunlight Foundation (who works there), and how does that relate to Open Data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [about page](http://sunlightfoundation.com/about/):

> The Sunlight Foundation is a nonprofit, nonpartisan organization that uses the power of the Internet to catalyze greater government openness and transparency, and provides new tools and resources for media and citizens, alike. We are committed to improving access to government information by making it available online, indeed redefining “public” information as meaning “online,” and by creating new tools and websites to enable individuals and communities to better access that information and put it to use.

In practical terms, Sunlight's open data work has several facets.  We do policy advocacy around encouraging openness in government (of which the POIA stuff is an example, as is the DATA Act), work with government agencies to figure out how best to expose data they've decided to open, and host an [annual transparency-oriented conference](http://transparencycamp.org/) of which open data is a major component.  Our Labs team, the technical arm of the organization, also both consumes and produces open data via our [tools](http://sunlightfoundation.com/projects/), which try to make government information more accessible to the public.

As for who works here: [here's a staff list](http://sunlightfoundation.com/people/).

(Disclosure: I'm a developer at Sunlight.  Sorry if this post comes across as overly self-promote-y.)

Comment: I'm a volunteer organizer who's collaborated with the Sunlight Foundation, and I want to add that they support (primarily through pizza-buying) community-building activities such as local project nights and meetups.  I'd also mention that their tools tend to fall into two categories: end-user-oriented browser extensions and web pages; and developer-oriented databases and APIs.  Through the latter, they're able to support a wide range of other projects.